# Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception IOS

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm getting this issue in Crashlytics and, I really don't know what is causing it. It show me that the error is in my AppDelegate, 15 line, but there is where the class beginning:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

This is the issue:

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException Application tried to
>   present modally an active controller RN.ViewController: 0x1509e200.

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000000206e6c5c

> 0 RN CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 986
>
> 1 RN CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 986
>
> 2 RN CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 722
>
> 3 RN CLSHandler + 30
>
> 4 RN __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 66
>
> 5 libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_client_callout + 22
>
> 6 libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 56
>
> 7 RN  CLSExceptionRecord + 250
>
> 8 RN  CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 614
>
> 9     RN  CLSTerminateHandler() + 544
>
> 10  libc++abi.dylib std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
>
> 11 
>     libc++abi.dylib__cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, 
>   _Unwind_Exception*) + 110
>
> 12    libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 250
>
> 13    UIKit-[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4640
>
> 14    UIKit__62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 336
>
> 15    UIKit-[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:] + 204
>
> 16    UIKit-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions] + 128
>
> 17    UIKit-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 108
>
> 18    UIKit-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 540
>
> 19    UIKit-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 204
>
> 20    UIKit-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 78
>
> 21    QuartzCore CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 252
>
> 22    libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_client_callout + 22
>
> 23    libdispatch.dylib_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1524
>
> 24    CoreFoundation  **CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 8
>
> 25    CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1574
>
> 26    CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
>
> 27    CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
>
> 28    GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 160
>
> 29  UIKit UIApplicationMain + 144
>
> 30    RN  AppDelegate.swift line 15

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the error is clear , search the whole project for present/push/segue at the same time

Comment: Do you use Appsee for recording all of your app sessions? 
I am facing similar issue. but very random. It started happening after Appsee's new changes in video recording.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with iOS 13. I ended up upgrading the Crashlytics library, since the Crashlytics team [fixed a few crashes for iOS 13](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).

Anyone who has these crashes on iOS 13 devices should upgrade Crashlytics to at least version 3.14.0.

Comment: Lifesaver - couldn't understand the crash message inside Crashlytics admin page

Comment: I am already running 3.14.0, but still I am getting the erro, please have a look the image for complete crashlytics URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYYQl.jpg

Comment: @MuhammadOwais That is not the same error. Your error is that SplunkNSURLSessionDataDelegateInterceptor does not have the setSession method. This is a different problem.

Comment: Hi @FrancoisNadeau , I am getting the same issue and unable to understand what is wrong, even I have updated the Crashlytics to the latest version.